# Web API + OData - Possible to use different models for GET and POST?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I'm using Web API with Microsoft's OData implementation to build a RESTful service. For a given resource (here, `Employee`) I would like to return one representation for GET requests (i.e. when retrieving the collection or a single record), but accept a *different* representation for POST and PUT/PATCH requests.

After building out my API project in this manner and attempting to create a new `Employee` via a POST request, I get this exception returned back:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "The request is invalid.",
        "innererror": {
            "message": "employee : The entity type 'Api.DataContracts.Manage.EmployeeCreate' 
             is not compatible with the base type 'Api.DataContracts.View.Employee' 
             of the provided entity set 'MyProject.MyContainer.Employees'. When an entity 
             type is specified for an OData resource set or resource reader, it has to be 
             the same or a subtype of the base type of the specified entity set.\r\n",
            "type": "",
            "stacktrace": ""
        }
    }
}
```

To further elaborate on my scenario, here's the model I use to return results for GET requests:

```
namespace Api.DataContracts.View
{
    public class EmployeeView
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string CompanyName { get; set; } // fetched from a related table
    }
}
```

So far, so good. But when I want to create a new `Employee` I don't want an `Id` field (the database creates this). Nor do I want to accept a `CompanyName` field, as what I need at create time is a Company ID so I can properly set the relationship in the database. So that model looks like:

```
namespace Api.DataContracts.Manage
{
    public class EmployeeCreate
    {    
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public Guid CompanyId { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

The relevant signatures on my `EmployeeController` OData controller are:

```
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("({key})")]
public IHttpActionResult GetEmployee([FromODataUri] Guid key)
// returns an Ok() with a EmployeeView model as the payload

[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute]
public IHttpActionResult AddEmployee(DataContracts.Manage.EmployeeCreate employee)
```

Lastly, I have this EDM model configuration:

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

builder.EntitySet<DataContracts.View.EmployeeView>("Employees");

// Had to add this to avoid a Media Formatter error
builder.AddEntityType(typeof(DataContracts.Manage.EmployeeCreate));
```

In my research, both here on SO and on the Web at large, I've seen people ask similar (but not exactly the same) questions. The answers tend to point that this scenario should be possible, but it appears the use of Microsoft's OData libraries may make this impossible.

I have not been able to figure out a solution or workaround to this problem. I've considered making one of the models a sub-type of the other (since inheritance is supported in OData) but that feels like it will potentially raise a new set of issues.

Has anyone successfully used a similar architecture with Web API + OData?